# Python - changing values of a dictionary when using itervalues()

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

I'm wondering if it is OK to modify the values of a Python dictionary when it doesn't depend on the keys:

```
# d is some dictionary containing classes I wrote
for v in d.itervalues():
    # modify v, and v's type may or may not change
```

I'm not sure what the Python standard says about this, could somebody please provide some information?

Thanks!

Comment: As v will be the same object, not copied, you can freely change it.

Comment: Yes, you can modify ones, but you should to choose another approach. Try to read few first chapters from official python doc.

Comment: What do you mean by "`v`'s type may or may not change"? How can an object's type change?

Comment: @larsmans: `obj.__class__ = SomeOtherClass`. Now whether that's a sensible thing to do is another question (and the answer is "obvioulsy, no").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean constructs like:

```
d = {1: [1]}
for v in d.itervalues():
    v[0] += 1
```

then yes, this is completely safe. The `dict` just stores a reference to the object in question and does not touch it in any way other than storage and retrieval. This is not explicitly documented, but it is implicit in the [definition of mapping](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) (of which `dict` is a subtype):

> A *mapping* object maps hashable values to arbitrary objects.

"Arbitrary" means the object may be mutable.